# PHP - set variables equal to contents of a DIV of an external web page

Tags: php, web, cron, dynamic-data

I'm making a clan website that I'd like to dynamically update from runescape's website to keep our clan data up to date. I'm planning on making a PHP script which I can execute daily via cron job that does 3 things:

1. Fetches a webpage
   (http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-home/clan/Quest%20Cape%20FTW)
2. Parses out the contents of 5 DIVs
3. Stores the value of these DIVs into 5 variables that can then be accessed by my other web pages.

So far:

1. I know how to fetch a webpage with `file_get_contents('http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-home/clan/Quest%20Cape%20FTW');`
2. I don't know how to separate out just the desired DIVs (`#Clanstat_1 .clanstatVal` to `#Clanstat_5 .clanstatVal`)
3. I know how to make the variables i.e. `$var1`, `$var2`, etc.

Can anyone help with step 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any great HTML Parser written in PHP.

Personally, I like this one - PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can then access any element of your HTML using jQuery-like syntax.